# WinRAR - Span Archives instead of splitting (Internet Archive)

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, archiving, winrar

I'm having a small issue trying to back up data to the Internet Archive.

I have tried to used 7zip to split files into certain sizes (such as 7G or 25G) to upload better, but IA won't accept extensions like .001. It needs to be able to access the zip/rar/7z in order to be accepted.

Does WinRar or 7-zip have an option to span archives (create individual archives at a set size) instead of split? I need to create individual archives in order to upload to Internet Archive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you use the CLI thing or the website? https://archive.org/developers/internetarchive/quickstart.html#uploading

Comment: @Gantendo I use both.